# How to localize mail app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iPhone app that sends an email with a report using MFMailComposeViewController.  I have localized the app into 6 different languages, both the storyboard files and the localization.strings files.  However, when I test it (both in the simulator and on the device) all of the Mail app buttons (Cancel, Send, Delete Draft, To, Subject, etc) are not localized.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was, I createt a new taget language file to solve this problem. Simply make one for each localisation:

[image]

After you done that try to change the language by going to settings ->general:

[image]

and from there you go to international:

[image]

from there to language:

[image]

and at this pint you simply change the default language to whatever you want and you localisations are. For example:

[image]

This should help you.

Answer (score 1):

The default iOS components are only translated if the OS knows that your app supports the current language.

Take a look at the info tab of the project settings (not the target settings).
There is a field where the available translations are listed.

Maybe Xcode didn't recognize your translations automatically and you have to add them here using the plus-button.